# How to handle DuplicateKeyError in MongoDB (pyMongo)?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

Could anybody please tell me how to handle **DuplicateKeyError** in MongoDB?

I am writing a python script, where I move several docs from two different  collections into a third one. There is a small overlap between the two collections due to having a few identical documents (with identical ObjectId). This results in the following:

> DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: admin.collection_test index: *id* dup key: { : ObjectId('593a920b529e170d4b8fbf72') }

In order to get rid of the error I use:

```
try:
    do something
except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
    pass
```

I expect by using of the "try-except" to move all non-crossing documents to the third collection, but instead the script just peacefully stops running once a first overlap (an already existing document in the collection) appears.
Would appreciate any help a lot!

Comment: your ObjectId already exist for this collection for another document

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
for doc in documents:
    client.update_one({'_id': doc['_id']}, doc, upsert=True)
```

You can use [update_one](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) with upsert=True. This updates doc with new doc if doc exists already otherwise it creates new doc.

Answer (score 28):

If you're iterating over the documents, try using `continue` instead of `pass`.

```
for doc in documents:
    try:
        # insert into new collection
    except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
        # skip document because it already exists in new collection
        continue
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer based on the original post's code example.

Answer (score -2):

## CONNECT TO DATABASE

```
connection = pymongo.MongoClient("192.168.2.202", 27017)
```

## CREATE DATABASE

```
database = connection['my_database']
```

## CREATE COLLECTION

```
collection = database['my_collection']
```

## INSERT DOCUMENTS IN COLLECTION

```
url="http://some/api/url/path/?format=json"
data = {
    '_id': url,
    'timestamp': datetime.datetime.now(),
    'data': {
        'XX': 1,
        'YY': 2,
        'ZZ':  3
    }
}
```

## TO AVOID DUPLICATES - THIS WILL CREATE NEW DOCUMENT IF SAME ID NOT EXIST

```
collection.update_one({'_id': url},  {"$set": data}, upsert=True)
```